# JDBC PrepareStatement parameters do not work for CREATE, DROP, ALTER

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I need to use JDBC to create a new Oracle user. The user name and password of the new user are provided by the user via a GUI. The following codes works fine (I can also use Statement instead of PreparedStatement).

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("create user " + username + " identified by " + password);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

However, since the user name and password are provided by the user, they may contain special characters like space, semi-column, quotes, etc, which may make the above statement invalid. I don't want my codes to be doing the validations of the user name and password, and to leave it to Oracle for the validation. Therefore, I thought of using parameters in the prepared statement instead:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("create user ? identified by ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

But it doesn't work at all. When I supply a valid user name and password, I will get "ORA-01935: missing user or role name". It seems that the parameters do not work for CREATE, DROP, ALTER statements. How to resolve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User name and password are not text values, but *identifiers*.

The `PreparedStatement` parameter markers (`?`) are used to supply dynamic values of various data types. They cannot be used to supply identifiers, e.g. you cannot do things like `SELECT * FROM ?` to dynamically specify the table name.

String concatenation is the only way, and you need to quote (`"`) the identifier if it contains special characters, just like the [documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CREATE-USER.htm#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C__BABHHFHD):

> If a password starts with a non-alphabetic character, or contains a character other than an alphanumeric character, the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), or pound sign (#), then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. Otherwise, enclosing a password in double quotation marks is optional.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I just need to use a normal Statement, and enclose the user name and password with double quotes. Thanks!